# how to send a push notification message to the specific target via APN ?

Tags: apple-push-notifications

We're planning to develop a new application.
this application will use a lots of different companies but application will be unique.let me explain it : our users will download this application from app store
after login process we will be able to understand which companies are using this application and who is on the line at the moment..

so my question is if I want to send a push notification to a specific company and it's users who use our application, how can we do that ?

let me give you an example :

We assume that there are 3 companies
First is A , second is B and other one is C
A has 10 users , B has 4 users and C has 40 users.

I want to send a push notification TO C's users ( in this example..).. A , B and C are using same application but their credentials are different from each other.
is it possible with your PN infrastructure ? Can you share with me your opinions ? My best

Comment: This is a rather lame question. It demonstrates no minimal understanding of how to architect a software able to differentiate different user groups.

Comment: yeah , maybe you're right. But I tought that it's enough.IMO , there is no need to detail information how we architect this potential solution.I just need to know whether it's possible or not. Thank your for your interest Marcell Fülöp...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very very broad question, 
but to lead you in the right direction, this is possible. It all depends on your method of implementing Apple's APN service. The push notification service is simply an API you can submit HTTPS requests to and it pushes the notification out to whatever devices you supply it.

The logic for whom receives these notifications is all up to you in your server side programming.

For example:
I am developing an app right now that uses a NodeJS server with the node-apn module installed. With this, I can connect to my Database where I store users device tokens (used to specify which device you are pushing to) then send a simple notification like so:

```
var device = new apn.Device("DEVICETOKEN");
var note = new apn.Notification();
note.payload = {custom:"objects", cango:"here", numval:56};
note.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000)+10; // 3 hours from now
note.badge = 3;
note.sound = "ringtone.wav";
note.alert = "This is a push notification";
apnConnection.pushNotification(note, device);
```

You should really do a little research before coming to SO with nothing, then expecting answers like this all the time when you haven't put any effort into it.

Comment: Thank you for your help.it's enough for me.My Best! btw , You're right my friend.I'll take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will have to upload each app to the apple store, meaning that each company will have to open development account in apple.
2. Companies will send you a requested licence for the app and for the server.
3. You will have to compile our app with this licence.

   - of course every app will have a apple ID.
4. You can send message from the server to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, port 2195.

Comment: Thank you Serjo!My best!